# when run projects in vs they just show up and disappear instantly

Tags: visual-studio

OMG!
when run projects in vs they just show up and disappear instantly
all of project's are c# console app and i ran them before and that was okay 
i've try to reset all setting and that didnt work

Comment: Di you add code since then the moment it was working? If you add a breakpoint and debug your program line by line, does it crashes (or throw an exception) somewhere or it runs each line with no problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your console app to whait for input you can put that at the end of your `main` method

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Then you need to hit `enter` to exit the console app.

Another possibility while debugging would be to add a breakpoint at the end of your `main` method.

Comment: Did your project have the same behaviour even with Console.ReadLine()?

Comment: It works in another solution with the same code? There must have been something wrong with you solution then...

Answer (score 0):

It was set to something wrong.

Project start up was set to **single project**, not **current project**.